# How to guard routes using localstorage on nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to be able to redirect the user for a login page if he access any route and is not logged in.

As simple as can be done, i'm trying to redirect the user to login, so I get the user from localstorage and if undefined or null i redirect to login, but this seems not work, because the user even logged never gets out of the login page, I did some research and understood that this is server side issue, but how to approach this ? What's the most common way of creating a guard using localstorage/indexedb cached user?

```
#utils

export const getUserFromLocalStorage = (): User | null => {
    const userStr = localStorage.getItem('user');
    return userStr ? JSON.parse(userStr) : null;
};
```

```
#middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { getUserFromLocalStorage } from './lib/utils';


export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const user = getUserFromLocalStorage()
    if (!user) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
}


export const config = {
    matcher: '/',
}
```

Comment: At its simplest, you may put together authentication endpoint using Next.js API feature which will return auth (JWT) token. Then you can store it in (http-only) cookie (not local storage for security reasons). After that, you would redirect every request that does not have valid cookie attached to login page. But that is too broad topic to be addressed in a single SO post.